# In Python, why subsetting with or without square bracket is different?

Tags: python, dataset

Suppose I have a data frame called quoteDF

```
quotesDF

              volume  shares
2017-01-03   2934300     100
2017-01-04   3381400     120
2017-01-05   2682300     140  
2017-01-06   2945500     160
2017-01-09   3189900     180
2017-01-10   4118700     200
```

If I do,

```
> quotesDF.loc[1, 'shares']
120
> quotesDF.loc[1, ['shares']]
shares 120
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Why the first one retunrs 120, the second one retures shares 120? In my mind, they are the same thing, except I put the second one in a vector. But, the first one is a vector stands by itself. It's just that I didn't put the square bracket on it.

Why Python give me such a confusing time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, you have a `pandas` dataframe, `.loc` is strictly label based. Since you're using `[]` it accesses the column you're specifying inside the brackets and that is the reason you're getting `shares 120`. Read [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/indexing.html) for better explanation.

Here is another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417991/pandas-why-are-double-brackets-needed-to-select-column-after-boolean-indexing) that has answers similar to your question.

Comment: very helpful links, I will loook into it. Thank you!